# Why does the "button" element works inside the "select" element only if there is an "input" element inside?

Tags: html

```html
<form action="select-button.php">
  <select name="selected-option">
    <option value="reset">Reset</option>
    <option value="submit">Submit</option>
    <input type="hidden">
    <button>submit</button>
  </select>
</form>
```

This works, but if you remove the "input" element, the "button" disappears. Why?

Comment: Likely the input implicitly closes the select, since this is all very invalid to begin with.

Comment: Why is it invalid? According to the technical info of the "select" element, the element can contain phrasing elements and content. The button is a phrasing element, so it should be valid to be contained inside select. There is also no problem having "input type button" inside.

Comment: Never mind. I just took a closer look, and it turned out i misread the technical summary of the "select element". I've confused "permitted parent" with "permitted content".

Comment: I’m not even sure how you’d expect a select dropdown with a button inside it to render…

Comment: *According to the technical info of the "select" element, the element can contain phrasing elements and content.* **Please add reference of that.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification allows only `optgroup` and `option` elements as children, as well as `script` and `template`:

> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmlselectelement

[image]

You probably misread "contexts in which this element can be used" into "content this element can have".

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned above, i misread permitted parent for permitted content. But still,  i am wondering why does the above code behave this way? If i add Input, the button appears, if i remove input, the button disappears. Why do you think that is?

Comment: There's no use in thinking about invalid HTML behaviour.